# In Dialogflow, how do I extract values for two different entities from a single word?

Tags: dialogflow-es

In my use case, I want to extract the value '*male*' in the entity **gender** and the value '*adult*' in the entity **age-group** from the single word '*husband*', or likewise, I want to extract the value '*female*' in the entity **gender** and the value '*senior*' in the entity **age-group** from the word '*grandmother*'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems that you will run into when trying to implement this in Dialogflow.

**1:** Dialogflow cannot extract multiple entities based on a single value. Even if you add a phrase twice with a different parameter it will only return one of the two entities.

**2:** Dialogflow cannot set entities based on the value of a different entity. If you wish to use something like this, you will need some code that does the setting of **gender** and **age-group** for you.

So you could create an entity and add *husband, wife, grandfather* and *grandmother* as values and then check this entity in your code and set variables in your code to male, senior etc.

---

The closest you can get without using any code would be by expanding to two entities in the parameters, this way you can add *husband* as a synonym for both entities:

[image]

For this example I've used the following entities:

[image]

[image]

Due to the synonym's Dialogflow will now change husband to a value of male when you expect an entity of Gender. The same trick has been used on the age-group entity for adult.

Finally, I've used the below intent setup to create the example:

[image]